# Remote Debugger Lag - Ignore Threads in Eclipse Debug Perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, remote-debugging

I have a program with hundreds of threads that I have to debug. If I don't have any breakpoints enabled, it takes about 3 seconds to run with the debugger attached. With a breakpoint enabled, it takes about two minutes for the debugger to show that we are suspended. Once I click resume, the program instantly finishes, but the debugger takes another two minutes to show that the thread is resumed.

I can't get rid of all the threads. The network is fairly fast between me and the remote point, I get about 300KB in each direction with a file transfer. I don't see very much eclipse network activity.

I'd like to understand this lag and get rid of it if possible. If it's caused by shoving all the thread state over the network, I'd like to ignore the threads I don't care about.

I'd like to ignore the hundreds of other threads, except for the one I need to debug. Or maybe ignore all of them until a breakpoint is hit.

If such a feature exists, I'd like to use it. If not, I'd want to create it.

So, as for a direct question: How can I speed up my remote debugging?

**EDIT**

I'm running a webserver type program on a test system. The only person accessing it externally is me, so the webserver stuff shouldn't be interfering with any other network traffic.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm asking a silly question, but these hundreds of threads - are they, by any chance, running network connections?

Comment: No, not silly at all. They shouldn't be. It's hard to say, but looking at my net monitor on the server, it's maybe 3KB in and out total, with large spikes up to a few meg. I'm not sure where that is going when it happens. More info above.